# Add custom form field to Joomla plugin admin

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I created a Joomla plugin that allows you to choose which scripts to load asynchronously in the head. This is done by entering keywords in a simple text field on the admin side. I thought it would be more helpful to allow users to choose scripts by radio button or checkbox.

I need to add a custom form field to my plugin that gathers these scripts as options and displays them in the proper format for the admin side. Currently getting a 500 error when looking at the plugin options in admin. I thought all I would have to do is change the getOptions() function for a JForm list field, but it's not working. Would appreciate some guidance on what all that function expects to take in and what it outputs.

/forms/scripts.php:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldScripts extends JFormFieldList {

public function getOptions()
{
    //$fieldname = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/', '_', $this->fieldname);
    $options = array();
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    foreach ($doc->_scripts as $url => $value) {

        $value = $url;
        $text = trim($url);
        $disabled = 0;
        $checked = 0;   
        $selected = 0;
        $tmp = array(
            'value' => $value,
            'text' => $text,
            'disable' => $disabled,
            'class' => '',
            'selected' => ($checked || $selected),
            'checked' => ($checked || $selected)
        );

// Set some event handler attributes. But really, should be using unobtrusive js.
        $tmp['onclick'] = 0;
        $tmp['onchange'] = 0;

// Add the option object to the result set.
        $options[] = (object)$tmp;
        echo $tmp;
    }

    reset($options);

    return $options;
}
}
```

Plugin xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.0" type="plugin" group="system">
    <name>System - JS Async</name>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Choose scripts to load asynchronously in the head.</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="js_async">js_async.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <folder>forms</folder>
    </files>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="file_names" type="text"
                       description="List of file names to load asynchronously."
                       label="File Name(s)"
                       size="50"
                />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset addfieldpath="/plugins/system/js_async/forms">
                <field name="title" type="Scripts"
                       description="blah blah blah."
                       label="File Name(s)"
                />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```